# cant access content of a file while using subprocess python

Tags: python, csv

Script A.py (python 3.0) does some work and creates a output.csv file.
Script B.py (python 2.5) takes output.csv as input and does some work.

Example A.py:

```
Outfile = open (path_to_csv, "w+")
Outfile.write(string_to_be_written)
Outfile.close
subprocess.call(["path/to/B.py", path_to_csv, args+])
```

Example B.py:

```
csv_file = open(path_to_csv, "rb")
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
for row in csv_reader:
    print row
```

Now when I run B.py directly, it works perfectly and prints each row of the csv.
But doesn't read anything when called from A.py with subprocess.call. It doesnt throw any errors while reading either.

I have tried using os.system and subprocess.Popen but they encounter the same problem. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is your path to csv relative or absolute?

Comment: The first line of Example A is problematic: `Outfile.write = open (path_to_csv, "w+")`

Comment: are you sure B even runs when launched through A? Is A creating the file properly / not crashing?

Comment: It should be easy to post a runnable example that we can commit on. Bugs like `Outfile.write = open (path_to_csv, "w+")` just confuse things!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake here, However I have not made that mistake in the actual code.

Comment: @ozking It is an absolute path.

Comment: BTW, per [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the first letter of *class* names should be capitalized, but `Outfile` isn't a class -- it's just a regular object, so its name should be all-lowercase.

Comment: To emphasize what tdelaney said -- if you'd tested that your example generated the *exact same error* when run, and provided everything needed to let someone run the test themselves, then we could could know for a fact whether a given answer solves your problem, instead of needing to guess at whether something is a typo. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidelines on asking a question in such a way that others can test their answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Outfile.write = open (path_to_csv, "w+")` is probably a typo, next line could work as is. You probably mean `Outfile = open (path_to_csv, "w+")`

Then the problem is that you don't actually close your file:

```
Outfile.close
```

accomplishes nothing. You need:

```
Outfile = open (path_to_csv, "w+")
Outfile.write(string_to_be_written)
Outfile.close()
```

else the file stays open/unflushed. On Windows, you cannot open it again (locked), on Linux it may contain unflushed data.

The most annoying thing as that when `a` finishes, the file is properly closed and you see the proper csv output, so it's misleading as why it doesn't work.

Better: use a `with` block to close file on exiting the block

```
with open (path_to_csv, "w+") as Outfile:
   Outfile.write(string_to_be_written)
# now call the subprocess outside the with block: the file is closed
subprocess.call(["path/to/B.py", path_to_csv, args+])
```

Even better: rewrite both scripts so output of the first one is consumed by input of the second one (avoids writing a temporary file just to pass data)

Comment: Ah, the solution is always simple with Python, isn't it?
As you pointed out correctly, I didnt make Outfile.write mistake ( a typo) but guilty on Outfile.close
Surprising thing is python didnt raise exception and let it run.
I have almost given up on why it isn't working before you came to my rescue.
Thanks for the solution.
It works!

Comment: on windows you'd have an exception because there are write file locks that prevent other process (or the same process) to read a non-closed file being written. In Linux, no such lock, so I suppose that buffering made that the file was not written at all to disk until process ends. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: @Shaardyy, why would it be an exception? Function objects have a value; if you refer to a function without calling it, you're looking up that value -- it's completely valid syntax, and has a useful meaning (albeit not so useful in the case, like here, where the looked-up value is immediately thrown away, and where the lookup itself is done without side effects).